# How to setup AngularDart with ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, angular-dart

I'm trying to run AngularDart along with ASP.NET Core as backend. 
I have following structure

```
wwwroot
---index.html
---main.dart

pubspec.yaml

app
---app_component.dart
etc
```

When I run my app in WebStorm it works fine but with Visual Studio I have a problem with packages. Actually I'm not really understand how it works even in WebStorm because I don't have such as folder, only .packages file and I've read that all packages store in my local user folder like (). How I can handle it?

I guess that I have to use pub serve but not sure how.

[image]

Comment: When you say with Visual Studio, do you mean Visual Studio or VSCode? VSCode has an up-to-date Dart plugin (Dart-Code) which will understand .packages files - the replacement for packages directory symlinks. Any plugin into Visual Studio is likely older and not maintained, and I wouldn't recommend using for current Dart development.

Comment: @DevonCarew Visual studio 2017